# Consecutive smooth number generator recovery

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, continued-fractions

The numbers $n=811150370266636218705704$ and $n+1$ have highest factors 173 and 167, and they happen to be the [largest consecutive 173-smooth numbers](http://11011110.livejournal.com/97325.html?thread=351533).

They were found via [Størmer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem) and the continued fraction method for solving the [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).  That means $n$ was generated from the numerator of a convergent fraction that solves $x^2 - 2 \sqrt{k} y^2 =1$.

Out of the $2^{40} = 1099511627776$ possibilities, what was $k$?  Is there a way to go backwards other than brute force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lehmer's procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem#The_procedure) involves solving the Pell equation
$$x^2-2qy^2=1$$
for $173$-smooth squarefree $q\neq2$.
(This makes $\frac{x}{y}$ an approximation for $\sqrt{2q}$.)
Then, for a finite number of smallest solutions $(x,y)$ of each Pell equation,
the integers $n=\frac{x-1}{2}$ and $n+1$ are tested for smoothness.

Therefore, the $x$ involved is $x=2n+1$, and the $q$ involved is exactly the squarefree part of $qy^2 = \frac{x^2-1}{2} = 2n(n+1)$,
that is, the factor of $2n(n+1)$ with largest square cofactor.
That cofactor is $y^2$.
Plugging in, we get
$$\begin{align}
qy^2 = 2n(n+1) &= 2^4\cdot3^3\cdot5\cdot7^2\cdot13\cdot19\cdot23^2\cdot43\cdot47^2
\cdot59\cdot61\cdot71\cdot83\cdot89
\\&\qquad\cdot103\cdot107\cdot109\cdot139\cdot151^2\cdot167^3\cdot173^2
\\\therefore\quad
q &= 3\cdot5\cdot13\cdot19\cdot43\cdot59\cdot61\cdot71\cdot83\cdot89
\cdot103\cdot107\cdot109\cdot139\cdot167
\end{align}$$
I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Very nice. That really works out beautifully.